# getting an error when trying to import the spamc library in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, spamassassin

I use python3.5, i recently installed spamc using pip.
When i try to import spamc, an error is raised:
How can i resolve this error?Should i find and install other library where spamc is included in it?

```
import spamc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    import spamc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/spamc/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from spamc.client import SpamC
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/spamc/client.py", line 230
    except socket.gaierror, err:
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: It looks like `spamc` is for Python 2. I'd suggest finding another library, or moving to Python 2.

Comment: how did you reach this conclusion?

Comment: `except ExceptionType, var_for_exception:` is Python 2 syntax.

Comment: thank you for your answer, do you know if exists in the wild a library like spamc made for python3 ? doing a google search, returned nothing about this.

Comment: No, I don't actually know what `spamc` is, sorry.